# Can a Yup schema report combinations of rule violations?

Tags: reactjs, forms, passwords, formik, yup

I'm using [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) to build a simple signup form with `email` and `password` inputs. I'd like to be able to show a user in real-time if their password conforms to some standard ruleset, such as

- It's required
- Minimum character length
- Must contain at least 1 digit
- Must contain at least 1 special character

Kindof like this example:

[image]

However, validation through [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) and indeed all of Formik's validation docs seem to populate an [`errors` prop](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#errors-field-string-string) object that only shows one validation error per-field, rather than reporting whatever combination are currently passing/failing.

For example, the `errors` object `{email: "Required", password: "Needs to be at least X characters"}` might refer to a password `"abc"` which is short, but also has no digits or special characters.

It's possible though! We can send `<Formik>` a custom [`validate`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#validate) function that populates the `errors` prop with all of the rules:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  validate={values => ({
    email: {
      required: ...,
      isEmail: ...
    },
    password: {
      required: ...,
      meetsMinLength: ...,
      containsDigit: ...,
      containsSpecial: ..., 
    }
  })}
  validateOnChange={true}
> 
  {formik => (
    ... render form, inputs, errors, etc ...
    ... "formik.errors" looks like "{email: {...}, password: {...}}" ...
  )}
</Formik>
```

This works, *however* I really enjoy how declarative [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) is and would like to continue using it. Is it possible to formulate a Yup `Schema` that will report all combinations of errors like this custom `validate` function?

Comment: Its a really good use case, I’m not sure but maybe we can achieve it through custom function using `yup.addMethod`.